# Why is Jesus at the center of everything

Tags: life-of-jesus

If you look through the Bible we know that Jesus is at the center of everything both in the old and new testament.

I have some clues like him being beloved or as a reward of what he suffered.

> **John 3:35**
>
> The Father loveth the Son, and hath given all things into
>   his hand

and

> **Philippians 2:8-9**
>
> 8 And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became
>   obedient unto death, even the death of the cross.
>
> 9 Wherefore **God also hath highly exalted him**, and given him a name
>   which is above every name

I feel my clues are not concrete or complete so I would like a broader view or complements.

Comment: Read the Book of Hebrews. The entire point of the book is "why Jesus is so more excellent then..."

Comment: Can you cite Old Testament scripture which specifically references either Jesus or The Son?

Comment: @Jim G. There is: _...For they [Israelites] drank from the spiritual Rock that followed them, and the Rock was Christ_ I Corithians 10:4. If you remember where Moses gave the Israelites from the rock

Comment: It is also claimed that the fourth person in the furnace where Abednego et al was thrown, was Jesus.

Comment: Am also interested more in the old testament reference, pre-earth and other relevant reference than the new testament. Jesus is everywhere in the new testament

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Reason 1

1. According to reformed theology, the Bible is about the Glory of God.
2. Jesus is God.
3. Thus, the Bible is about Jesus.

More concretely, [some](http://www.reformedonline.com/view/reformedonline/Chosen%20by%20God.htm) would go so far as to state that the Elect is the father's gift to the Son (I'm not sure if this can be scripturally verified). That would be further reason for the Bible focusing on Christ.

### Reason 2

Without Jesus, these would be no forgiving of sins. Without the forgiving sins, the Bible would be a very different book.

Comment: "According to reformed theology, the Bible is about the Glory of God."

According to which theology then the Bible **isn't** about the Glory of God?

Comment: I grew up in a church where the teachings was much more focused on "human morality / being a nice person / being the type of person that others would want to be around => converting them to Christ." When I started reading reformed theology -- it was quite a shock, where the focus was almost entirely on the attributes of God.

Comment: @unregistered-matthew7.7 Are you sure that you aren't me?

Comment: @SanJacinto: I also like Compilers, AI, Machine Learning, and Software Architecture. However, I don't like embedded systems. :-( In fact these days, I can't imagine programming in anything besides Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
>   was God. He was in the beginning with God. **All things were made
>   through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made.** In
>   him was life, and the life was the light of men. The light shines in
>   the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.    (John 1:1-5 ESV)

Jesus is the center of everything because He is the *Logos* (ie Reason/Word) of God and everything God created was through Him (ie Reason/Word) and through His incarnation He provides the "touchpoint" between the created and the uncreated.

Answer (score -1):

Throughout our life what do we look for? The purpose of life don't we?  The questions **every** human ponders in life is:

1) *How did we get here? Who made all of this stuff we see*?  (**The Truth**)

2) *What is our purpose in life? What should we do?*  (**The Way**)

3) *How can we stay alive and be healthy? How can we/should we live?*  (**The Life**)

Don't you know the very question you ask is one Jesus answered over 500 years ago?

*5 Thomas said to him, “Lord, we don’t know where you are going, so how can we know the way?”*

*6 Jesus answered, “I am the **way** and the **truth** and the **life**. No one comes to the Father except through me.*

The beginning of everything we know starts at the **origin**. For example, before you were conceived you were **0**, or in a mathematical sense at the **origin** (since the origin is located at **(0,0)**). Notice that the **center** is the **origin** where everything began. Thus, Jesus is undoubtedly the center of life because he is simultaneously the meaning of life in being that he is the **origin** of life (as far as we know today).

Comment: This answer would be acceptable if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it.    Answers are not to be used to express your opinions or make comments/observations, but rather well-sourced answers as to what is taught by some group within Christianity. Typically, we expect the question to ask for a specific denominational or doctrinal perspective.  In this case, the question should have been closed in the first place because it's phrased in such a way that it leaves it open to opinions.

Answer (score -2):

> Why is Jesus at the center of everything? If you look through the Bible we know that Jesus is at the center of everything.

Technically, he's not. **God** is at the center of everything.

As Christians we believe in the Trinity, and the Trinity has three "parts"*: Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. Jesus is one of these parts, but it would be incomplete to say that Jesus is at the center of everything.

Furthermore, your question referred to **The Bible** and did not qualify the question by saying **The New Testament**. Surely you'd agree that most of the Old Testament speaks about **The Father**, and the New Testament, after Pentacost, speaks about **The Holy Spirit**.

*Disclaimer: I realize that the word "parts" is an insufficient word to describe the Trinity.

Comment: It's kind of hard to read things like Collosians 1:15-20 and not come away with the idea that Jesus is at the center of everything specifically because God saw fit for it to be that way. Obviously as a member of the Trinity this is played out in all three persons, but the Scriptures from start to finish place a special emphasis on the Son as the reason/purpose/end/center. And no, one must not agree that the NT doesn't continue to talk about the Father.

Comment: @Caleb Did I say that the NT stops speaking about the Father?

Comment: You implied that there is somehow a shift of focus off of the Father in the OT to the Holy Spirit in the NT. I'm trying to say that the focus of both testaments is the Son and that there is continuity between them in a way that your statements imply there is not.

Comment: A biased opinion that holds no merit. It is very clear that Jesus is god, as he reaffirms it many times. Now if you want to argue error in the scriptures, then you may have some kind of argument, but that is a different debate.

Comment: @Shammy: But Jesus is just one component of the Trinity.

Comment: You are correct, but you are allowing simplicity to convolute the meaning of the trinity. The trinity consists of the Father, Son, and the Holy Spirit. Don't you remember when Jesus said "I and the Father are one?", "I am in the Father, and the Father is in me" . It follows that the Holy Spirit, God and Jesus are one force. The mouth, eyes, and ears are all functions of the body. Can any of these functions work properly without the brain? Of course not, they are worthless. Do we then say that the ear is independent of it's controller (the brain)? Of course not.

Comment: Went over the character limit for a reply post, but in essence, Jesus is the center and purpose of everything we know in the New Testament. The Old Testament is countless stories of covenants broken and reaffirmed, followed by a promised final convenant (a messiah) when God will dwell with humans on earth. The promised messiah has came. He is.